# I have a blade in laravel that gets messy

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

On local it works fine but when send to prod everything gets down as if the sizes where different sometimes a space gets ignored other its like there is a double space.
I have tried using bootstrap, pure html but always gets different, also on mac it doesnt even render.

Comment: Did you check if your styles/js are loaded , check the network tab (F12)